# C++ with OpenMP giving -not-a-numbers (nan) in N-Body Simulator

Tags: c++, openmp, physics

I am working on learning about parallelization and particularly OpenMP. I have a sequential N-Body simulator that works perfectly and gives correct outputs, but when I add in a parallel for, all my x,y positions output as -nan.

There are no race conditions in this algorithm, and parallel for creates an implicit barrier, so this should work if I am not mistaken (which it appears I am).

When I output `new_pos` in certain stages, I start to get numbers like 64.4358358.53. I don't understand how numbers like this could even exist, let alone be represented by the computer.

Any ideas as to what is causing them?

```
for( int t = 0; t < TOTAL_STEPS; ++t )
{
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( N ) 
    for( int q = 0; q < N; ++q )
    {
        forces[q][X] = forces[q][Y] = 0;
        for( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
        {
            if( q == k ) continue;

            x_diff = pos[q][X] - pos[k][X];
            y_diff = pos[q][Y] - pos[k][Y];
            dist = sqrt( x_diff * x_diff + y_diff * y_diff );

            // performing a calculation with a distance this small introduces
            // small denominator errors
            if( dist > 0.01 )
            {
                dist_cubed = dist * dist * dist;
                forces[q][X] -= 1 / dist_cubed * x_diff;
                forces[q][Y] -= 1 / dist_cubed * y_diff;
            }
            else continue;
        }

        pos_new[q][X] = pos[q][X] + vel[q][X] * timestep;
        pos_new[q][Y] = pos[q][Y] + vel[q][Y] * timestep;

        vel_new[q][X] = vel[q][X] + ( forces[q][X] * timestep );
        vel_new[q][Y] = vel[q][Y] + ( forces[q][Y] * timestep );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < N; ++ i )
    {
        pos[i] = pos_new[i];
        vel[i] = vel_new[i];
    }

}
```

Notes:

1. I know that N threads are not optimal, but it was just part of the exercise
2. for prototyping, I am using G = 1 and all masses = 1, which is why my formulae may look incorrect

Comment: Are you copying pointers in `pos[i] = pos_new[i];`? Then perhaps you should swap the pointers so that the two vectors stay different.

Comment: add `private( x_diff, y_diff, dist, dist_cubed )` to your `parallel` directive

Comment: Thanks, I actually realized this after a good night of sleep. I can't mark your answer as correct since this is a comment though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gilles pointed out, the solution was to make the local variables private.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads ( N ) private( x_diff, y_diff, dist, dist_cubed )
```

was the only required change